# Bragg's diffraction and Simon's problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In Preskill's notes, [John Preskill](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/) goes as

> If we scatter a photon off of a periodic array of needles , the photon is likely to be scattered in one of a set of preferred directions , where the Bragg scattering condition 
>   is satisfied.

and further

> These preferred directions depend on the spacing between the needles , so by scattering just one photon , we can already collect some useful information about the spacing.

How can the analogy with Bragg's diffraction help me understand Simon's problem ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the notes?

Comment: @KyleKanos 
http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/#lecture

look in chapter 6 , page 67 , para 3